# OOM Killer value always one less than set

Tags: kernel, proc, out-of-memory

I am trying to set the `oom_adj` value for the out of memory killer, and each time I do (regardless of the process) I get back exactly one less than I set (at least for positive integers.  I haven't tried negative integers since I want these processes to be killed by OOM Killer first).

```
[root@server ~]# echo 10 > /proc/12581/oom_adj
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/12581/oom_adj
9
[root@server ~]# echo 9 > /proc/12581/oom_adj
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/12581/oom_adj
8
[root@server ~]# echo 8 > /proc/12581/oom_adj
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/12581/oom_adj
7
[root@server ~]# echo 7 > /proc/12581/oom_adj
[root@server ~]# cat /proc/12581/oom_adj
6
[root@server ~]#
```

Is this expected behavior?  If not, why is this happening?

Comment: You probably want to be using `oom_score_adj` instead. `oom_adj` is deprecated.

Comment: That's actually kind of interesting. I'm not seeing that when I modify `oom_adj` on any of my systems. What kernel version are you running?

Comment: @JoelDavis I'm current running Fedora 19, 3.13.9 (`3.13.9-100.fc19.x86_64`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oom_adj` is deprecated and provided for legacy purposes only. Internally Linux uses `oom_score_adj` which has a greater range: `oom_adj` goes up to 15 while `oom_score_adj` goes up to 1000.

Whenever you write to `oom_adj` (let's say 9) the kernel does this:

```
oom_adj = (oom_adj * OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX) / -OOM_DISABLE;
```

and stores that to `oom_score_adj`. `OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX` is 1000 and `OOM_DISABLE` is -17.

So for 9 you'll get `oom_adj=(9 * 1000) / 17 ~= 529.411` and since these values are integers, `oom_score_adj` will hold 529.

Now when you read `oom_adj` the kernel will do this:

```
oom_adj = (task->signal->oom_score_adj * -OOM_DISABLE) / OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX;
```

So for 529 you'll get: `oom_adj = (529 * 17) / 1000 = 8.993` and since the kernel is using integers and integer arithmetic, this will become 8.

So there... you write 9 and you get 8 because of fixed point / integer arithmetic.

Comment: Nice well researched answer. This is exactly the stuff we need here on U&L.

Comment: Wow, that is really interesting and makes perfect sense.  Thank you!